# RegAsm cannot loading dependencies from another directory

Tags: c#, .net, regasm

I have some DLLs in a subfolder which I need to register a tlb for using RegAsm. These DLLs have some dependencies which reside in the parent directory.

When running RegAsm on these DLLs, however, there is an error saying that the dependencies could not be loaded because `the system cannot find the file specified`. The Dependency DLLs have been registered with RegAsm themselves and I even tried adding their directory to the PATH variable, and yet RegAsm cannot load them because it says it can't find the file.

If I copy the dependencies into the subfolder, then they will register, and vice versa if I copy the DLLs in the parent folder they will register. However, this is not a great solution.

I was wondering if there was some RegAsm commandline option or a config file variable which I can use to specify that dependencies need to be loaded from elsewhere... Anybody know?

Comment: That does not sound like an error message produced by Regasm.  More likely is that you got it when you tried to use the registered assembly.  The CLR still looks for dependent assemblies in the usual places, first the GAC, the same directory as the EXE next.  With the normal hangup that you did not copy them into the EXE directory.  Using the GAC is pretty important for [ComVisible] assemblies, on your client's machine, since they have a nasty DLL Hell problem.  ILMerge.exe and AppDomain.AssemblyResolve are alternatives.